# Change the length of FileStream in c#

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [FileStream Append Data at the top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062003/filestream-append-data-at-the-top)

I have a file stream opened with write permissions.
I am trying to 'delete' data from the stream, but i cant find out how. I need a solution such as changing the stream's Length property.
Does some one have ant idea?

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the current suggested duplicate.

Comment: @sixlettervariables: Ah, wait, looks like you are right.  I misread that question, they were trying to insert data into the beginning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`Stream.SetLength`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.setlength.aspx).

> If the specified value is less than the current length of the stream, the stream is truncated.

Comment: damn I feel dumb :) I saw a Length property with only a getter, and I never saw the use of setter method this way in c# before... Anyway - thank you very much Jon, as always... ;)

Comment: @PiniSalim: I don't think it would be appropriate for Length to have a setter.  If nothing else, I would find it rather counterintuitive for a property setter to be permitted to throw a `NotSupportedException`.

Comment: Position already does this (throws NotSupportedException if the stream can't seek):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.position(v=vs.110).aspx

The reason it isn't a property is because properties aren't supposed to be used for potentially "expensive" operations. Seeking is fast, but setting the length of a file could take a while.